# Solving three-equations nonlinear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am stack at solving the following non linear system

$$\dot{x}= x(1-x-y-z)-ax$$
$$\dot{y}= y(1-x-y-z)-ay$$
$$\dot{z}= z(1-x-y-z)-az$$

where $a<1$ And  the empty space 1 − x − y − z.

And I can only find its trivial solution $(0,0,0)$

How can I find its non trivial steady state solution?

The definition of steady state is the point $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ such that $\dot{x}=0$ ,  $\dot{y}=0$ ,  $\dot{z}=0$

That is I need to find the solution of the following system

$$0= x(1-x-y-z)-ax$$
$$0= y(1-x-y-z)-ay$$
$$0= z(1-x-y-z)-az$$

Thanks a lot

Comment: What’s $/dot x$? Or $/dot y$ or $/dot z$. Is it derivative? If so, by which variable?

Comment: @mdave16 first order differential equations.

Comment: Okay, I have explained clearly. Please look at the question box again. Thanks @mdave16

Comment: @mdave16 there was no need to grill OP so much, $\dot{x}$ is an *extremely* common notation for $\frac{d}{dt}$ and that much should have been inferred from context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w=x+y+z$. Then we have that

$$\dot{w} = \dot{x} + \dot{y} + \dot{z} = w(1-w)-aw$$

$$\implies \int dt = \int\frac{dw}{w(1-a-w)} = \frac{1}{1-a}\int \frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{1-a-w}dw$$

by separation of variables. Solving, we get

$$(1-a)(t+C) = \log\left(\frac{w}{1-a-w}\right) \implies w(t) = \frac{1-a}{1+Ce^{(a-1)t}}$$

We can plug this back in to get the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = (1-a)\left(1-\frac{1}{1+Ce^{(a-1)t}}\right)x \\
 \dot{y} = (1-a)\left(1-\frac{1}{1+Ce^{(a-1)t}}\right)y \\
\dot{z} = (1-a)\left(1-\frac{1}{1+Ce^{(a-1)t}}\right)z \\ \end{cases}$$

which is now fully decoupled. We can solve them by using the fact that

$$\dot{x}(t) = f(t)x(t) \implies x(t) = C\exp\left(\int f(t) dt\right)$$

so we get

$$x(t) = C_x \exp\left((1-a)\int 1 - \frac{e^{(1-a)t}}{e^{(1-a)t}+C}dt \right) = C_x \frac{e^{(1-a)t}}{e^{(1-a)t}+C} = \frac{C_x}{1-a}w(t)$$

with equivalent answers for $y$ and $z$.

To find nontrivial steady state solutions, notice that the $w$ equation was in the form

$$\dot{w} = (1-a-w)w$$

so either $w=0$ or $1-a-w=0$. The steady state solutions are all constants such that

$$w(t) = 1-a$$

or in other words, $x(t)+y(t)+z(t) = 1-a$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I add some important information about the question. Please look at the question box. Is it enough to find unique solution. I need to find steady state point in fact.

Comment: @user315 I'm about to edit the answer because I found a way to more fully proceed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am waiting for the edited version of your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Here $\dot{w}$ is equal to zero. So how can I find it? Again I find trivial steady state solution.

Comment: @user315 check it now

Comment: I am so sorry. But I don’t understand. Why there are no exact values $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$?

Comment: @user315 because there are an infinite number of answers...

Comment: Okay. I’m gonna think again. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? The question states that “  the empty space 1 − x − y − z“. Then, should I assume $x+y+z=1$?

Comment: @user315 I'm sorry I don't know what that means. And no, you shouldn't assume that. Look at the answer and tell me why.

Comment: Hmm yes I see. I added the original solution. When I look at the question, I need to find an exact solution. But, you are right as well... I confused. Please you also look at the original question.

Comment: For example, in the original question, in the next step, which steady state point will I use?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to the system of equations are
x = y = z = 0.
x = y = 0, z /= 0, a + z = 1 and coordinate permutations.
x = 0, yz /= 0, a + y + z = 1 and coordinate permutations.

The case a = 1 needs a closer look.

Comment: But $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0) $ is trivial steady state solution. I don’t need this.